# HDFS path in Azure HDInsight Cluster

Tags: r, azure, hadoop, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

I have provisioned an Azure HDInsight cluster type ML Services (R Server), operating system Linux, version ML Services 9.3 on Spark 2.2 with Java 8 HDI 3.6.

Within Rstudio Server I am trying to read in a csv file from my Azure blob storage.

However, the package (sparklyr) I'm using in R only allows for paths that are hdfs: or file: and not the http: (path provided by the azure blob), in the spark_read_csv() function.

If data hosted as an Azure storage blob has a hdfs: path and how I go about finding the correct path to use?

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `wasb:`? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/hadoop-azure/index.html#Accessing_wasb_URLs

Comment: If possible, you should look at your `fs.defaultFS` setting in a `core-site.xml` file... Hopefully HDInsights already sets this to be some Azure storage

Comment: Hey @cricket_007 thanks for the response. So the wasb: is correct path type for accessing the Azure blob storage. However the function I am trying to use in R's package Sparklyr https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/versions/0.9.2/topics/spark_read_csv

requires "The path to the file. Needs to be accessible from the cluster. Supports the "hdfs://", "s3a://" and "file://" protocols."

Comment: The Azure blob storage is the default storage type when setting up the HDInsights cluster so I'm guessing its all configured correctly but that I just don't know how to access it correctly using the path argument of the spark_read_csv() function.

Comment: Hey @cricket_007 so I looked up the fs.defaultFS and found the following values. Do you suggest I need to change this to point to the azure storage path?

`configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>`

Comment: If youre not running HDFS, then yes. Spark will either read that config file, or you must give the full URL, like that page says